# Bringing in Schedules for Access calculations

Tags: ms-access, schedule

I really don't know how to ask this question or title it but here I go. I work in a school system and I have created a database for some psychologists to use to track their referrals. By state rules,they have 60 days from the date of their first meeting to finish the process. Weekends still count but HOLIDAYS DO NOT. I do not really know how to use the calender we have so that we have an accurate Calculation. For instance, with Holidays accounted for, if a kid was started today, he would need to have everything finished on 1/18/2013 That is 60 days from now based on our schedule. Does anyone have any idea where I should start?

Edit

Ok, so I now have a Calender table. Here is my issue. I have my column that I used to indicate which days are used in calculating my 60 days. Weekends can be used in that calculation. HOWEVER, they cannot be used in the result. If the 60th day lies on a Sunday or Saturday, then  the date would need to go to the Friday before.  I guess my first issue is really, how do I limit my calculation to the dates in my calender table?

Comment: Have you considered a calendar table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263492/how-do-i-automatically-insert-monthly-records-into-a-table-via-sql/12263731#12263731? Where are your holidays stored?

Comment: I don't have anything stored yet. I've done a good bit with databases, but I am just starting to really get into the fine details like this.

Comment: Calendar tables are very useful indeed in any database that needs scheduling. They do not take much space.

Comment: Ok, well it seems that I need to learn about Caldender Tables. They don't seem too hard.

Comment: So I have a calender table, that isn't hard at all. My problem now is how do I then calculate based on ONLY The days listed in that Calender while also restriction my output to the dates in that calender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the weekday to ensure you have not chosen a weekend:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CalDate, WDay 
FROM (SELECT Top 60 c.CalDate,Weekday([Caldate]) AS WDay
      FROM Calendar c
      WHERE c.Holiday=False) a
WHERE WDay Not In (1,7)
ORDER BY CalDate DESC
```

Comment: I actually have a calender set with the weekends and holidays taken off. At this point, I just need to know how can I do a calculation based on those days and not what access normally would do if I told it to do (date + 60)

Answer (score 1):

This can be easy with a calendar table.

```
PARAMETERS start_date DateTime;
SELECT TOP 1 sub.the_date
FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 60 the_date
        FROM tblCalendar
        WHERE
                the_date>=[start_date]
            AND work_day=True
        ORDER BY the_date
    ) AS sub
ORDER BY sub.the_date DESC;
```

That query is based on the assumption you have set `work_day` to `True` for the dates you want evaluated.  IOW, `work_day` will be `False` only for your organization's holidays.

For sample code to create and load your calendar table, see the `CreateTable_calendar()` and `LoadCalendar()` procedures at [Using Start Date and End date in Access query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9303628/77335).  To initially assign all dates including weekend days as work days, make this change in `LoadCalendar()`.

```
'rs!work_day = Not (Weekday(dte) = vbSunday Or _
'    Weekday(dte) = vbSaturday)
rs!work_day = True
```

Finally, manually edit the table to change `work_day` to `False` for your holidays.

Comment: OK... so I am not exactly sure where to put this to be honest. The more I have worked on it, the better I wish I asked my question though. I actually will need to use weekends for my calculation, but they can't be used in my answer. For instance, if the due date was on a weekend, then it would need to move back to the Friday before.